# Erase vs ReDim In Arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

**Background:**

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127809/excel-vba-variant-array-reusable-must-be-erased) and made me learn about [erase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83zyeke9.aspx) statment in arrays.

I have always used the following to reset them:

```
Sub TestWithRedimOnly()
Dim ExampleArray() As String
    ReDim Preserve ExampleArray(1)
    ExampleArray(1) = "yo"
    MsgBox ExampleArray(1)
    ReDim ExampleArray(0) As String
    MsgBox ExampleArray(1) 'this confirms is reset!
End Sub
```

If I do it with erase

```
Sub TestWithEraseAndRedim()
Dim ExampleArray() As String
    ReDim Preserve ExampleArray(1)
    ExampleArray(1) = "yo"
    MsgBox ExampleArray(1)
    Erase ExampleArray
    MsgBox ExampleArray(1) 'this confirms is reset!
    ReDim ExampleArray(0) As String
    MsgBox ExampleArray(1) 'this confirms is reset!
End Sub
```

At the end, both reset the variable.

**Question:**
Is it really worthy to use erase statement? Does it prevent memory leaking better than just the `Redim.. As..` Are there any cases that you can recall about not doing it like so?

Comment: One difference is that after redim a(0) you still have an allocated array with 1 index at a(0).  Erase exists to destroy an array, so if thats what you want to do thats what you may as well use.

Comment: Is it really worth to call the erase? I mean an array with 1 index with nothing on it vs an array totally destroyed and then re build -if I want to re use the array variable-

Comment: `Erase `does what you intend `ReDim ExampleArray(0)` to do in your example, except it does it "better" and is shorter to type and clear in intent.  Personally I can see no reason not to use it.

Comment: So at the end, are they "code synonyms" -in terms in reliability/speed/memory usage/intention- and are up to the coder style?

Comment: No, they are different in behaviour; accessing `arr(0)` would throw an error after `Erase` but not after `ReDim`

Comment: You are right, since the other one would not have even index 0 to start with. For practical purposes, is really a difference of "resetting" with index 0 the array than with erase that completely cleans the array?

Comment: Why would not using *either* of them leak memory? They'll get garbage collected when they leave scope regardless.

Comment: Yeah I use one of them, just were wondering which one was the best and why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, go with the semantics:

- Use `ReDim` to *re-dimension* an array
- Use `Erase` to *deallocate* an array

Sticking to that will make your code benefit from greater consistency and will make your code's intent clearer to the reader/maintainer/future-you.

Comment: I guess this is a good advice, even though one may behave similar to the other one, for standardized purposes, Erase would be a better way to go.

Answer (score 6):

Since you asked about the consequences of Redim vs Erase specifically in regards to memory... The only practical difference is with dynamic arrays.

If you erase a non-dynamic array it sets the values in it to 0s, zero length strings, or "empty" for variants. eg: Dim Array(10)

If you erase a dynamic array it completely frees the memory. eg: Dim Array()

Neither option should result in a memory leak. Both should cause memory to free up in a way that doesn't constantly expand the memory used if you loop through the array and redim/erase array parts of your code. If you are running into a memory leak looping through code, that might be a better question to ask about.

From the help on erase:

```
Dim NumArray(10) As Integer ' Integer array.
Erase NumArray ' Each element set to 0.

Dim StrVarArray(10) As String ' Variable-string array.
Erase StrVarArray ' Each element set to zero-length string ("").    

Dim StrFixArray(10) As String * 10 ' Fixed-string array.
Erase StrFixArray ' Each element set to 0.

Dim VarArray(10) As Variant ' Variant array.
Erase VarArray ' Each element set to Empty.

Dim DynamicArray() As Integer ' Dynamic array.
ReDim DynamicArray(10) ' Allocate storage space.
Erase DynamicArray ' Free memory used by array.
```

Comment: Yeah `ReDim NumArray(10)` allocates the memory for an array index 10  -or 11 based on base- (hence being different from resetting the variable),but, if I do `ReDim ArrayDesired(0) as Integer` instead of `Erase NumArray` what's the difference?

Comment: It is a nominal difference at best. If you do Dim arr()
ReDim arr(0)
Erase arr() and step through you will see that a redim(0) is still an array of 1. An erase arr() empties it entirely.